# Fruit sales for the past 2 weeks

Tags: visual-c++

Guys  would like to calculate the number of guava's sold + the other fruits listed
then multiply them by multiplying by 2

this is my code  have been trying to  do it but its confusing please may you help!

Comment: I don't see any code.

Comment: @Tanaka, Welcome to the site! Please read the “how to read a question” at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, so others could help you with your issue. Notice you did not provide any code, and your current question doesn’t allow anyone to help you, since it’s not clear what you need. Please edit your question, so it won’t be deleted.